# Set Spinner based on the other Spinner

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I'm making an App for android. I have 2 `spinner`s, and when I select one item in my 1st spinner(`simpleSpinner`) it ofc needs to show it(I have done that) but when I select one from my 2nd spinner(`multiSpinner`) I want my `simpleSpinner` to go back to the first item in the spinner. And the other way around, when I select one in my `simpleSpinner` I want my `multiSpinner` to show the first item in my `simpleSpinner`. How do I do that?

```
 final ArrayAdapter<String> ar1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.my_spinner, arrSimple);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> ar2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.my_spinner, arrMulti);

        spSimple.setAdapter(ar1);
        spMulti.setAdapter(ar2);

        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener simpleListen = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                String simpleText = spSimple.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if("Rouge".equals(simpleText)){
                    spMulti.setSelection(0);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        };

        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener multiListen = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                String multiText = spMulti.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if("Plein".equals(multiText)){
                    spSimple.setSelection(0);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        };
    spSimple.setOnItemSelectedListener(simpleListen);
    spMulti.setOnItemSelectedListener(multiListen);
```

The code works now! Thanks to @BlackPanther

Comment: obviously, you need to show your code..

Comment: @BlackPanther done that now, Sorry!

Comment: by "going  back to the first item" do you mean that by clicking one spinner, the other spinner should default to the first item on the list?

Comment: @BlackPanther Yes that's what I tried to say ;)

Comment: You're welcome... ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use separate listeners for you `Spinners`. Since you are using the same listener for both the `Spinners` this piece of code

```
if("Rouge".equals(simpleText)){
    spMulti.setSelection(0);
}
```

causes your problem.

When you have first selected "Rouge" in your first `Spinner` the second spinner is set to "Wahie", now when you try to change the item in your second `Spinner`, the same method is invoked and since the first `Spinner`'s selection is in "Rouge" the second `Spinner` is set to "Wahie" again..

In your `onCreate` method do something like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  //your code

  addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

  //more of your code
}

public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
  spMulti = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spMulti);
  spMulti.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
}
```

you can create a custom listener class that implements `OnItemSelectedListener`

see [**this article**](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/). You can adapt from it and tailor it according to your need.

You can use the same listener for both the spinners by the following code

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parent;
 if(spinner.getId() == R.id.spSimple)
 {
   //do this                    
 }
 else if(spinner.getId() == R.id.spMulti)
 {
   //do this
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked! Thought it would be easier to do it all in one listener, but thank you for the help!

Comment: happy that i was of help :)